# Angular & jsonStub post

Tags: angularjs, json

So i am using online tool to fake backend for creating json and restful services, although I know how to create one.

But the company that applied for the job requires, to do CRUD app with [jsonstub](http://jsonstub.com/).

It works great with GET request I can fetch data, and everything.

But when I try, to POST, something it doesn't work.

The JSON file stays unchanged.

Maybe my code is problem ?

Any help would be much appreciated thanks in advance

```
$http({
    url: 'http://jsonstub.com/nemke/test',
    method: 'PUT',
    dataType: 'json', 
    data: {
    first_name:$scope.newUser.name,
    last_name:$scope.newUser.last_name,
    cv_file_name:$scope.newUser.cv.name,    
    },         
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'JsonStub-User-Key': '9de0ebf1-494e-49db-bae5-7efbbf3d0b25',
        'JsonStub-Project-Key': '1d5a1cd7-33fa-4838-918b-e11d9fd75081'
    }
}).then(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    data = 'asfsa'; console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
});
```

here is html

```
<form ng-model="newUser" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" id="first_name" name="name" placeholder="first_name" ng-model="newUser.name">
<input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name" placeholder="first_name" ng-model="newUser.last_name">
<input type="file" id="cv" name="cv" placeholder="cv" fileread="newUser.cv">
<input type="submit" ng-model="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: You said post but your code http method says put.

Comment: it doesent' work with method post also, sorry for typo

Comment: can you post your html code? maybe err in it

Comment: posted html edited my post

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try it

```
$scope.newUser={};
$http({
    url: 'http://jsonstub.com/nemke/test',
    method: 'PUT',
    dataType: 'json', 
    data:$.param($scope.newUser),
/// 
}
```

And I see in input cv you dont have ng-model , try add this

```
 <input type="file" id="cv" name="cv" placeholder="cv" fileread="newUser.cv" ng-model="newUser.cv>
```